# Firebase - Failed to get document because the client is offline (v9 Upgrade)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently upgraded to firebase v9 from v8 in my React Native project and I am now unable to use my legacy v8 firestore methods.

### The error I am receiving is:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the 
client is offline.]
```

I initialize firebase in a file I call fire-config.js. The commented `//import firebase from 'firebase';` is how I previously imported firebase in v8.

I then would import fire from fire-config.js into my controller methods. Ex: userController.js.

I tried a couple different combinations of `/compat` and `/compat/app` to no avail. I was following the upgrade guide (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which my understanding was update the path and that was all that was needed.

#### Package.json:

```
"firebase": "9.0.2",
```

#### fire-config.js

```
//import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat'; 
require("firebase/functions");
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
    appId: "XXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX"
  };
try {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch(err){
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)}
}
const fire = firebase;
export {fire};
```

#### userController.js

```
import {fire} from "../config/fire-config";

const getUserDetail = async (user) => {
  let userDetail = {};

  await fire
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        userDetail = {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        };
      }
    });

  return userDetail;
};
```

Comment: Have you managed to get anywhere with solving this? I have been having the same problem for the last few days but I have not upgraded to v9 yet - I am occasionally getting the same issue with v8. Not sure if our issues are related or not but seems odd we are both seeing this at the same time.

Comment: Nope, still swirling the drain on this one. Please upvote the question if you think it's related. Currently going to go back to v8 until I have more time to troubleshoot. @Tech

Comment: I spoke with a customer facing this issue and found they were getting the error on their laptop but not on their mobile. Both connected to the same WiFi and both running the same script. The customer informed me that they are using a VPN on their laptop so I am wondering if it could be related to that?